# WP7 - Splash Screen not working outside debugger session

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

When my MainPage loads in my Windows Phone 7 application, it triggers a popup splash screen that includes a progress bar and a graphic in a usercontrol.  After displaying the spash screen I do some work in a BackgroundWorker thread to load some resources while the spash displays.  When the loading is done I dismiss the popup.  This technique is well documented on [WindowsPhoneGeek](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/All-about-Splash-Screens-in-WP7-ndash-Creating-animated-Splash-Screen).

I noticed today that while this is working flawlessly when running in debug under Visual Studio, if I run the same build directly without the debugger connected, the splash screen animation and progress bar never appear and the DoWork() thread takes at least twice as long to execute the same operations.  I can see that the MainPage constructor gets called as well as OnNavigatedTo, but the  popup still does't display and the default jpg splash image remains on the screen, until the worker thread completes.  Then the popup displays for < 1 second and the mainpage displays.  Again, this all works flawlessly when debugging through VS 2010.

This is all in the Emulator, I don't have a device yet.  I just noticed this today, and coincidently(?) I just updated the environment to 7.1 last night.

```cs
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        IDictionary<string, object> state = Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.State;

        if (!state.ContainsKey(STATE_WAS_LOADED))
        {
            state[STATE_WAS_LOADED] = "LOADED";

            this.LayoutRoot.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

            _popup = new Popup();
            _popup.Child = new NPGSplash();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}: Displaying Splash Popup", DateTime.Now.ToString("ss.ffff"));
            _popup.IsOpen = true;

            // Asynchronously load the biggest dataset
            StartLoadingData();
        }
    }

    private void StartLoadingData()
    {
        _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(_worker_DoWork);
        _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(_worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void _worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}: Splash RunWorkerCompleted", DateTime.Now.ToString("ss.ffff"));
            this.LayoutRoot.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            this._popup.IsOpen = false; 
        });
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I ended up buying a device on ebay this week to ensure that I don't release an app where I can't confirm that it works properly.  I can confirm that whatever the problem is, it does NOT occur when running the application on the device.  Good news.  Still, I can't explain what appears to be an approximately 3-5 second pause in my application after the consrtuctor is called.  I even changed my logic in the constructor to set a `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` to fire in 100ms to kick off my logic.  When this code executes, the constructor completes, but the timer doesn't tick for 3-5 seconds.  Very odd, and only in the simulator when not attached to the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here would appear to be that you are never attaching the `Popup` control to the visual tree. To be honest, I've got no idea why this would work with the debugger attached either, but I'm going off what I can interpret from your code.

What I think you need to do is to add the `Popup` control as an element in the XAML for `MainPage` so that it is attached to the visual tree.

One other thing I'd say is that it's perhaps worth moving all the data loading code out of the constructor and into either an override for `OnNavigatedTo` or a handler for the `Loaded` event. Generally speaking, it's best to keep constructors and short and simple as possible (and yes I appreciate that you're using a background worker to load the data).

Comment: I was thinking the same thing with regard to putting the init code in `OnNavigatedTo`.  I tried that and it behaves identically.  I'll have a look tonight at the idea of putting the popup in the XAML.  I've never tried that.